# Image displaying in a browser but not in a HTML compiler

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, web-server, html

My image is displaying correctly in a browser, but when i use the image link inside an HTML compiler, its showing a broken image symbol.
Image link : http://winterminer.com/glogo.png
`<img src="http://winterminer.com/glogo.png" alt='fail'>`
I m using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, Apache web server installed through webmin/virtualmin.
I m struggling with this thing for weeks, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SSL/TLS certificate is broken. Therefore, the browser can't display it.

Do you call this image from a HTTPS website?

When you add this HTML code to a website that uses SSL/TLS, then the modern browsers will call "http**S**://winterminer.com/glogo.png"

It should be working fine, when you add this HTML code to an HTTP website.

Comment: i m not following, i tried this tag `<img src="http://winterminer.com/glogo.png" alt='fail'>`
on w3scools html editor, its not displaying. I dont have ssl, do i need to install one

Comment: i've enabled ssl for my domain and its working fine, thank you